# Number of rows with specified number of null columns

Tags: sql, null

How to get information how many rows in a table have particular number of nulls in it?
I want to get something like this:

```
Number of nulls | Number of rows
        0       |      10
        1       |       4
        2       |      11
```

**Motivation**:
I need this for data mining purposes. If for example I have an observation that has in almost all columns null value then I need to get rid of this observation, but there can be also a situation where many observations have small value of nulls which is acceptable.

Comment: By number of nulls do you mean the number of columns that have a null value?

Comment: Yes, I meant number of columns that have a null value.

Comment: What RDBMS? What table structure?

Comment: Will you not also need the name of the table in your result? Seems a rather pointless query to create an aggregate value of nulls across all fields of a table. What are you *really* trying to find out?

Comment: I'm working in SQL Server and I want this info for some particular table lets say 'Empoyees'. It is easy to get info about nulls for each columnt independently, but it doesn't say if those nulls are grouped  (by grouped I mean that some observations have null in all columns).

Comment: In response to my own comment I now see what you are after. In *one* table you want to know there are 10 rows with no null values, 4 rows with 1 null value, etc. etc. But I still do not see the value of such a query? For example, is this a set of answers and you want to know how many questions have not been answered?

Comment: What is the structure of the table (particularly do all columns of interest have the same datatype)? How can it be Null in all columns? Do you not have a PK?

Comment: The thing that I wrote is a sample answer just to show what I want. The question is how query should look like? It may be assumed that columns do not have the same type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just SQL, you'll have to resort to unpleasant code, something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + ... AS num_nulls,
       COUNT(*) as num_rows
FROM table 
GROUP BY num_nulls;
```

Also note that not all SQL dialects support referencing a calculated column by alas in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you might end up with a much uglier query. Needless to say, you'll also have to make a different query for each table. You could of course generate the query using some `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` voodoo...

Comment: Great! This looks like exactly what I wanted, althought it's a shame that different query needs to be written for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select MyCol, Count(MyCountCol) from 
(select 0 + 
      case  when Col1 is null then 1 else 0 end 
      + case  when Col2 is null then 1 else 0 end 
      -- + whatever other col names are in your table  
      as MyCountCol

from MyTable)
group by MyCol
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 you can do

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
pk INT PRIMARY KEY, 
c1 INT,
c2 INT,
c3 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1,1,1,'foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,NULL,'bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,NULL,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,NULL,NULL,NULL


SELECT Num AS [Number of Nulls],
       COUNT(*) AS [Number of rows]
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(c) FROM (VALUES(cast(c1 as SQL_VARIANT)),
                                                    (c2),
                                                    (c3)) T (c)) CA(Num)
GROUP BY Num
```